# perl regular expression match substring

Tags: regex, perl

I have several strings from which I want to extract a substring. Here is an example:

```
/skukke/integration/build/IO/something
```

I would like to extract everything after the 3rd `/` character. In this case, the output should be

```
/build/IO/something
```

I tried something like this

```
/\/\s*([^\\]*)\s*$/
```

The result of the match is

```
something
```

Which is not what I want. Can anyone help?

Comment: It sounds like what you *really* want to do is to create file paths relative to `/skukke/integration`. You should avoid pattern matching and use the [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec::Functions) module and the `abs2rel` function. But you need to explain better what it is that you need before anyone can write a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Regex Solution

The regex you can use is:

```
(?:\/[^\/]+){2}(.*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT8eL9/1)

Regex explanation:

- `(?:\/[^\/]+){2}` - Match exactly 2 times `/` and everything that is not `/` 1 or more times
- `(.*)` - Match 0 or more characters after what we matched before and put into a capturing group 1.

Here is a demo on [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMc1NsVmJDRGFMSlE):

```
$str = "/skukke/integration/build/IO/something";
print $str =~ /(?:\/[^\/]+){2}(.*)/;
```

Output:

```
/build/IO/something
```

## Non-regex solution

You can use [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec::Functions):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Spec;
$parentPath = "/skukke/integration";
$filePath = "/skukke/integration/build/IO/something";
my $relativePath = File::Spec->abs2rel ($filePath,  $parentPath);
print "/". $relativePath;
```

Outputs `/build/IO/something`.

See [demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/Q8djTj)

Comment: @Downvoter: https://goo.gl/YX5KQr is for you. Downvoting working solutions is BAD.

Comment: sorry for asking, what is the purpose of ?: at the beginning of the regex?

Comment: The `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group) to make matching less resource-consuming. Anyway, we are not using that value. If you need it, add round brackets (a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) around the whole beginning part: `((?:\/[^\/]+){2})(.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Regex:**

```
my $string = "/skukke/integration/build/IO/something";
$string =~ s/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*//;
```

Hope This helps.